# Accessing a local postgres database from a rails app running on a Minikube cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a rails app running on a Minikube cluster locally. However this app is unable to talk to the postgres database that is outside this Minikube cluster. (Just like my production environment would be)

I run in to a `could not connect to server: Connection refused is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IIP connections on port 5432`

I have added the following:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: host.docker.internal
  ports:
    - name: port
      port: 5432
```

Does my rails app need any special configuration?
is there another way to do this? What host/port do I need to specify for my rails app?
Thanks!

Comment: "127.0.01" ?  do you mean 127.0.0.1?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` in Kubernetes always means "this pod"; it isn't a reference to another pod, the node, or (in a virtualized environment) the host the node VM is running on.